# fail2ban doesnt work (Ubuntu/SSH)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, fail2ban, linux-vserver

i installed fail2ban it doesnt work im trying all the day to configure jail.conf..
this is my jail.conf(yes i changed the original one, my fault...)

enabled = true
port    = ssh
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
maxretry = 3
bantime = 60s
findtime = 60s

and i changed:

banaction = ufw

im not familar with the linux firewall is that enough?P fail2ban doesnt work can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file under following path and name as "jail.local", so it would be:

```
 /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Add the following content to the file.

```
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 ::1  
bantime = 3600
findtime = 10
maxretry = 2
[sshd]
enabled = true
port     = ssh,22
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=22, protocol=tcp]
```

You may alter the port if you are using any port number other than 22 for default ssh port. Also timings cloud be altered based on your needs.

**ignoreip** is the whitelisted IP addresses, which you don't want fail2ban to block them in any cases.

Please restart your fail2ban service after updating the file content.

```
systemctl restart fail2ban
```

Comment: when i connect with winscp fail2ban works correct. Is it perhaps just normal that fail2ban cant ban a already established ssh connection?

Comment: it shouldn't be like that either with WinSCP or command line, if it reaches the number of failed login, your IP should be banned.